# Outputting an array using recursion

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion

I am trying to write the contents of an array using recursion. My code looks like this:

```
static void Foo(int[] myArray)
{
    int i = 0;
    Console.WriteLine(myArray[i]);

    if (i < myArray.Length)
        return;

    i++;

    Foo(myArray);
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] myArray = {4,6,78,9,0};

    Foo(myArray);
}
```

However, when I execute the application, instead of the expected output:

```
4
6
78
9
0
```

It is only printed the first element:

```
4
```

I would like to receive advice that will help me find the right solution

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, [not as pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/328193).  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Additionally... This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That `i` variable doesn't maintain state between different function calls.

Rather you would need to pass `i` as an argument to the function and update it with the recursive call.

```
static void Foo(int[] arr, int i) {
    if (i >= arr.Length) return;

    Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
    Foo(arr, i + 1);
}
```

Then call in `Main`:

```
Foo(myArray, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another option for fun:

```
// Foo() is now generic and expects an IEnumerable, instead of an array
static void Foo<T>(IEnumerable<T> arr) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(arr.First());
    var next = arr.Skip(1);
    if (next.Any()) Foo(next);
}

// but Main() is UNCHANGED: still using an int array
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    int[] myArray = {4,6,78,9,0};
    Foo(myArray);
}
```

See it work here:

> https://dotnetfiddle.net/053Bbp

If you're just finding recursion, you're likely not familiar with generics, IEnumerable, or the LinQ operations. However, these features are **really important** to the language, and you WILL want to eventually understand them. You'll use them 1000 times more than you will use recursion.

In this case they likely make the code slightly slower, but not in ways you're likely to notice. The new code also has the advantage of working with **any type of collection** (not just arrays) where the items have a reasonable override for the `ToString()` method. That is, the code is *more capable and reusable*. The code is also "cleaner" in that it only requires one argument to `Foo()`.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps consider making a `Span<int>` of your array. Then you can write this:

```
static void Foo(Span<int> span)
{
    if (span.Length > 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(span[0]);
        Foo(span.Slice(1));
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] myArray = { 4, 6, 78, 9, 0 };
    Foo(myArray);
}
```